# sheet copy event in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I am trying to capture an event which is triggered when copy of an existing sheet has been created in the workbook. My intention here is to check how many copies of the worksheet exist in the workbook and therefore, limit the number of copies.

Comment: Then see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

There is no Sheet's Add event. You need to use `Application.SheetActivate` or `Workbook.SheetActivate` or the `Worksheet.Activate` event. Here is a C# example

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.SheetActivate +=
    new Excel.AppEvents_SheetActivateEventHandler(
    Application_SheetActivate);
}

void Application_SheetActivate(object Sh)
{
    // Your code here to check if the copy is a duplicate or not
}
```

Comment: This event handler is known to me. The question is :what must be the logic in order to find the new sheet created is a copy of an existing one. One of the approaches can be to iterate over the worksheet collections and match the name of the current worksheet. Here name of the newly created worksheet plays a big role. e.g if sheet whose copy has been created has name "Sheet1" and one created is "Sheet1 (1)" and there exists another sheet whose name is Sheet1 (2). Now the question is how to decide which is the source copy of the created worksheet.

Comment: One assumption can be that all sheets in the workbook must have unique and meaningful name. In this way a solution can be achieved with the help of worksheet name property and using string operations. isn't it?

Comment: No you will not use the worksheet name but compare the contents of the worksheets. If you search google, you will find lots of code to do a sheets comparision.

Comment: I have got a solution. I would post it soon.